# Git a local branch using a specific tag

Tags: git, github

How do I checkout a git tag and work on local branch(tag)?

origin/myremotebranch  (non-master branch)

with tags as:

myremotebranch-tag-v1.0
myremotebranch-tag-v1.1
myremotebranch-tag-v1.2

I want to checkout myremotebranch-tag-v1.1 and work on newlocalbranch-tag-v1.1

I am running the following commands:
git checkout -b  newlocalbranch-tag-v1.1 myremotebranch-tag-v1.1

But when I run git pull on the new local branch myremotebranch-tag-v1.1, I am getting the following error

There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch>  newlocalbranch-tag-v1.1
```

Can anyone explain me why I am seeing this branch without tracking?

Comment: That kind of makes sense. Tags don't move (not in general, you can force it to move if you want) so if you created a branch _from a tag_, there is no point in using it as upstream because.... **the tag** won't move.

Comment: So just checkout newlocalbranch, make my changes and push it to github/gitlab for the repo-master to merge with the master? or I --set-upstream-to=origin/<remotebranch>, pull, make changes and push my localrepo?